# Error de acceso a los nombres definidos en un Excel usando Interop

Tags: excel, interop

Estoy realizando un programa en C# (Visual Studio 2015) desde el cual tengo que actualizar un excel que tiene una serie de fórmulas, etc.

He decidido utilizar Interop en lugar de otras librerías como open xml o epplus porque necesito actualizar ciertos campos y posteriormente leer los valores de celdas que contienen fórmulas que referencian a las celdas modificadas.
Usando openxml no obtengo los valores actualizados. Además el excel tiene código VBA que se ejecuta en el change de una celda, que supongo que no se ejecuta si uso openxml.

Usando Interop sí me permite actualizar un campo y leer el valor actualizado de los campos de fórmulas pero tengo el siguiente problema:
El excel tiene definidos unos 1200 nombres para identificar los campos y al intentar acceder desde c# algunos de los nombres los reconoce pero otros no.
El nombre existe en la lista de nombres pero al intentar acceder da error.

Utilizo el siguiente código:

```
excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = true;  
excelApplication.Visible = true;
excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;   
excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(txtFicheroEntrada.Text);
wsDatos = excelWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
wsDatos.Select();

foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name v in excelWorkbook.Names)
{
    string NombreVar = v.Name;
    //aqui encuentra el nombre definido
    if (NombreVar == "BobinadoAT" ){ Console.WriteLine(NombreVar); }
}

if (wsDatos.Range["BobinadoAT"] != null) //aqui casca al intentar acceder 
{
    string valorcelda = wsDatos.Range["BobinadoAT"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Es curioso porque algunos de los nombres sí los reconoce. Desde el Excel si selecciono el nombre en la lista tampoco me lleva a la celda correspondiente.

¿Alguien ha tenido problemas con los nombres?

Comment: Los String en C# Se comparan con  ¿¿ ==  ??

Comment: Si los campos son de tipo string puedo compararlos con ==. Si fueran objetos no porque compararía por referencia.

Comment: Los string en c# se comparan con equals... con == estás comparando la dirección de memoria...

Comment: Si los campos son string internamente utiliza .Equals por lo que en este caso compara los contenidos. Puedes comprobarlo fácilmente. Otro caso sería si los defino como object. De todas formas lo cambiaré para que queda más claro. No obstante el error no se da ahí sino al intentar acceder al valor de la celda.

Comment: lo único que veo es que tienes el archivo con extensión .Text, no existen (CREO) esa extensión, sería .txt para los textos planos, pero no existen celdas. deberías usar un archivo.xls o archivo.xlsx

Comment: Es que estoy cogiendo la ruta del fichero de un campo de la ventana, pero lo que abre es un fichero .xlsm (que es un excel habilitado para macros).

Comment: Quizás en el foro inglés puedan ayudarte mejor

Comment: ¿Podría ser que los nombres que te dan problemas estén mal definidos en el propio archivo Excel? Es decir, que hagan mención a algo que ya no existe y están como #REF!

Comment: Los nombres están correctos porque si yo abro el xlsm directamente desde Excel y selecciono el nombre me lleva correctamente a la celda correspondiente. El problema se produce cuando lo abro a través de Interop.